# Groovy dynamic class with method with parameters

Tags: groovy, dynamic-class

I am new to Groovy and trying to create dynamic classes with methods with parameters. I went through the following thread and it helped me to get started: [Create a Groovy class dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160278/create-a-groovy-class-dynamically) .

But it didn't show how to create add methods with parameters to the dynamic class. Basically, I am looking for the code to generate classes in runtime with a method that has parameters like below

```
String id
setId(String newId) {
    id = newId
}
```

Comment: The link you point already provides you the answer. you can write `builder.addMethod('setId') { id = newId }`. Do not forget to add the `id` field to your class.

Comment: Ronin, what's the reason you need this?

Comment: if you are that new, maybe try to learn groovy (and java) class-loading mechanics first?